# how to make add see more featues in UILable if length of string is more than the number of line display in lable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i count the require lable size using below code

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:instructions.font 
                            constrainedToSize:instructions.frame.size
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

i count the number ofline of lable using below code

```
 int numberofline = ceil(lable.frame.size.height / font.lineHeight);
```

in my case i require only 3 line on the button click the hole text display in tableview...due to modifing the cell height...

//please help me to check how to get number of characters for given font family....

![this is demo image][1]
see image on following link
[click to view image demo][1]

Comment: Use textfield instead of label if ur text going to more than lines u defined , so it will add scroll..you can set userinteraction disable

Comment: Your question is so full of misspellings, grammatical errors, and non-sentences that it's hard to tell what you're asking. I THINK you are asking how to resize a UILabel so that it is tall enough to display a given block of text. A couple of things don't make sense, though. Why calculate the number of pixels needed, then convert back to a number of lines? You can set the line height of a label to 0 and it will display as many lines as needed.

Comment: Another issue is that your post ends with what I think is supposed to be a link to an image, but it is badly formed. You should fix that.

Answer (score 2):

set property of `UILable` **noOfLines = 0** which is by default **1**. this will automatically increase your **number of line** .